# when i open a file, nothing will be displayed - C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Premise: I'm using CLion.

As i said in title, when i try to open a file (txt) nothing will be displayed.
i can't explain it, i don't think i made an error, it's pretty easy this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {

FILE *leggi;
leggi = fopen("lorem.txt", "r");

char datiLetti[1000];

while(fgets(datiLetti, 1000, leggi)!=NULL){
    cout << datiLetti << endl;
}

fclose(leggi);


system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

file "lorem.txt" is in the same directory of the project.
Thank you in advance.

EDIT1: file is lorem not lorem_ipsum, my mistake when i typed here.

Comment: Test if `fopen` returns `NULL`.

Comment: First of all, there *is* text in the file? Secondly, the `fopen` doesn't fail? Thirdly, why don't you use the standard C++ streams and `std::string` for input?

Comment: Your program probably runs in a different directory than the project directory.

Comment: Don't tag random languages that you're not using.

Comment: `leggi = fopen("lorem.txt", "r");` here `lorem.txt` should be present in your current directory. if not then enter full path. also check if there is any content in the file. if not then nothing will b printed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i will try to use streams, btw fopen doesn't fail

Comment: How do you *know* it doesn't fail?

Comment: @AntonioPanicali did you try what I suggested in my answer below?

Comment: @MichaelWalz i tried everything but the program still not showing nothing, it opens, it closes. I tried with some cout or printf, nothing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because the window appears and disappears, showing nothing

Comment: @AntonioPanicali what do you thinks happens if `fopen` fails?

Comment: @MichaelWalz probably the window disappears, or at least showing my if with printf or cout

Comment: @AntonioPanicali wrong answer. If the file can not be opened, [`fopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) returns `NULL`. You need to check that as it has been suggested in my first comment and in my answer.

Comment: @MichaelWalz how i can check it? with if(fopens ==NULL){cout << something;}?

Comment: @AntonioPanicali sigh,... look at my answer. Read the chapter dealing with functions in your C textbook.

Comment: @MichaelWalz sorry i forgot to check your answer. Btw it show "Can't open file" for a millisecond, then disappear (with this test, if returns NULL)

Comment: Call `system("PAUSE");` before `return 1`, or run your program from the terminal. So your doesn't exist in the directory where your program runs.

Comment: Try running in the debugger. And actually *check* if `leggi` is not `NULL`!

Comment: @MichaelWalz done, but now i see an error: if i put system("PAUSE"); before return 1; it write sh: PAUSE: command not found

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude checked, it's not null

Comment: Put your executable and the file in the same directory, run the program from the explorer. Not CLion. It should run correctly. If it runs correctly it means (And will definitely be) that CLion runs your code in a different directory. Find which is it and put your file there from now on. Also, ALWAYS check for improper initialization (aka NULL or whatever) on code you make. Always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---FIXED---
Installed cygwig1.dll and cygstdc++-6.dll and put cygwig in glob variables, then my file worked in the same directory of main and exe.
However, thank you guys for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
...
FILE *leggi;
leggi = fopen("lorem.txt", "r");

if (leggi == NULL)
{
  cout << "Can't open file" << endl;
  return 1;
}
...
```

Comment: I'd recommend the use of `perror()` - that can help indicate whether it's a permissions problem, for example.  Most likely is that the working directory is not what the questioner thinks it is.

Answer (score -1):

fopen is a C solution for open a file if you want to open a file in c++ use fstream like flowing code.
fopen is deprecated in c++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    fstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.txt");
    cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno);
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, replaced example.txt with my file, but again: Unable to open file. ( i think in your code i have to change only "example.txt")

Comment: maybe your path incorrect or you haven't permission to open this file.

Comment: It say: error: 'myfile' was not declared in this scope
     if (myfile.is_open())

Comment: i tried to declare myfile outside the try catch, it works, but again it show Unable to open file

Comment: where is your file?

Comment: now: Error: No such file or directory Unable to open file. but why? it's in the same directory

Comment: I think my CLion have some bugs, or i can't explain it

Comment: in the same directory of project folder, where is the main.cpp